# iOS iPad custom calendar control

Tags: ios, view, calendar, schedule

Is there any custom calendar control for iPad that could help me create a schedule-view ? I just need the schedule view to make new appointments. This is what I want to accomplish :
[image: scheduler]

Maybe you could give me some suggestion on how to approach this. I am new in iOS development so any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of calendars on [Cocoa Controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com).

One of them seems to look like what you want : [MADayView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/madayview).

[image: Screnshot]

You may also look at :

- [OCCalendar](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/occalendar)
- [MAWeekView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/maweekview)
- [Kal](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/kal)
- [Tapku Calendar](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tapku-calendar)
- [CKCalendar](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ckcalendar)